# Why doesn't Unity's Dash recognize all games on my system?

Tags: unity, games, unity-dash

I have many more games in /usr/games than show up in Unity's Dash. If i do a search for games using Unity, a lot of mine are skipped. How does Unity decide what category a piece of software belongs to?

Comment: Can you give examples of which games don't show?

Comment: Here are some: blackjack, cgoban, gnugo, gtali, Xevil. There are plenty more that aren't recognized, all in usr/games. To be clear, I am mousing over "Applications" then searching for "Games" and looking in "Installed". Unity says I have 50 games installed but there are WAY more than that...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you open the Dash, click "More Apps" and expand the "Installed" section, are you able to find the missing games in there? I'm wondering if Unity's not filtering them properly or if it outright doesn't notice them.